# Вылетает из всех сессий telethon python telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.events import NewMessage
import asyncio

APP_ID = '1*****'
API_HASH = '8b6edcfa6a27eca********4b'

HEART = ''
COLORED_HEARTS = ['', '', '', '', '❤️', '']
MAGIC_PHRASES = ['magic']
EDIT_DELAY = 0.5

PARADE_MAP = '''
00000000000
00111011100&
01111111110
01111111110
00111111100
00011111000
00001110000
00000100000
00000000000
'''

client = TelegramClient('tg-account', APP_ID, API_HASH)


def generate_parade_colored():
    output = ''
    for c in PARADE_MAP:
        if c == '0':
            output += HEART
        elif c == '1':
            output += choice(COLORED_HEARTS)
        else:
            output += c
    return output


async def process_love_words(event: NewMessage.Event):
    await client.edit_message(event.peer_id.user_id, event.message.id, 'i')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await client.edit_message(event.peer_id.user_id, event.message.id, 'i love')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await client.edit_message(event.peer_id.user_id, event.message.id, 'i love you')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await client.edit_message(event.peer_id.user_id, event.message.id, 'i love you forever')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await client.edit_message(event.peer_id.user_id, event.message.id, 'i love you forever❤️')


async def process_build_place(event: NewMessage.Event):
    output = ''
    for i in range(8):
        output += '\n'
        for j in range(11):
            output += HEART
            await client.edit_message(event.peer_id.user_id, event.message.id, output)
            await asyncio.sleep(EDIT_DELAY / 2)


async def process_colored_parade(event: NewMessage.Event):
    for i in range(50):
        text = generate_parade_colored()
        await client.edit_message(event.peer_id.user_id, event.message.id, text)

        await asyncio.sleep(EDIT_DELAY)


@client.on(NewMessage(outgoing=True))
async def handle_message(event: NewMessage.Event):
    if event.message.message in MAGIC_PHRASES:
        await process_build_place(event)
        await process_colored_parade(event)
        await process_love_words(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('[*] Connect to client...')
    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
    client.session.save()
```

Сессии вылетают и код не отрабатывает до конца, подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Сколько не пытался найти решение в интернете, сколько не пытался изменить код (я думал, что проблема в нем) - все коту под хвост. Лично у меня проблема оказалась в том, что сессия на телефоне, сессия на пк и сессия бота открывались на одном айпи. Попробовал открыть бота на втором своем аккаунте, на котором сессия была открыта только на телефоне, и вуаля - не вылетает от слова совсем. Попробуйте тоже посмотреть свои сессии и айпи сессий, может у вас проблема тоже заключается в этом)

Comment: Если у вас появился вопрос, то нажмите [задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Зонтик Не понимаю вас. Человек посоветовал то что помогло ему, почему он дложен задавать вопрос?

Comment: @EzioMercer "столкнулся с той же проблемой" + описание неудачных попыток + неуверенность в совете - очень похоже на другой вопрос.

Comment: @Зонтик То что в ответе есть предыстория какая-та - это не значит в ответе нет полезной информации, чтобы помочь вопрошающему. "описание неудачных попыток" - может помочь вопрошающему не повторять ошибок автора ответа. "неуверенность в совете" - автору помогло что-то, но не факт что вопрошающему поможет ровно тоже самое + даже если не поможет лично вопрошающему, то может помочь другим, с такой же проблемой. У нас тут база знаиний как никак,  а не ответы лично вопрошающему